# How to strip all img tags from a text, except for those containing a certain word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to strip all img tags from a certain text, except for those which contain a certain keyword (e.g. the domain they're hosted at).

Here's what I've come up with, but I'm afraid it doesn't work:

```
 $text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+(?!keyword)[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! :)

Comment: I don't think regular expressions are a good idea for this as HTML isn't a regular language and cannot be correctly parsed by a regular expression. Have you considered using an HTML parser instead?

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback` to externalize the keyword matching logic. Otherwise try a HTML toolkik like phpQuery or QueryPath which allow for a simple `qp($html)->find("img[href*=keyword]")->remove()->writeHTML()"`

Comment: your example is a little ambiguous, is the keyword an attribute? is it unique within the text? will it occur within other parts of text outside of images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a callback to simplify the task:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback('/<img\s[^>]+>/i', "cb_keyword", $html);

function cb_keyword($matches) {  // return empty str or original text
    return !strpos($matches[0], "keyword") ? "" : $matches[0];
}
```

If you are working on HTML snippets using phpQuery/QueryPath would still be possible, but adds more post-processing.

Comment: Somehow, I just can't get this to work. This here replaces all image tags:

$text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);

This should do the same, but it replaces nothing:

$text = preg_replace_callback("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "cb_keyword", $text);

function cb_keyword($matches) {  // return empty str or original text
    return "";
}

Comment: @Dave: Works for me. You are not assigning it back, some WP problem, test it separately. Also remove the extraneous backslash before the closing angle bracket.

Comment: Never mind, it works great (than you VERY much!). I dare say it, but I was so greedy to get this going, that I placed the function into another function. Duh. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)? It uses libxml under the hood which is fast and robust.

**Don't try to parse HTML with regex's.**

I made that bold because I see it a lot on here and the solutions are always fragile at best and buggy at worst. Once you use a true HTML parser to get the attributes you want then using a regex is more reasonable.

*[update]* - Even if this is coming from Wordpress you should be fine since it takes a string as an argument.

> The function parses the HTML contained
>   in the string source. Unlike loading
>   XML, HTML does not have to be
>   well-formed to load.

Something like the following should get you going...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($var);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Comment: If you had attempted to give example code instead of just a link you would realize why people avoid it. And the question wasn't about **parsing**, but matching. Contrary to the misunderstood meme, regexps are perfectly fine for this case.

Comment: I disagree, "I would like to strip all img tags from a certain text" that is both parsing and manipulating. Regexes are for working with regular languages and HTML is not regular, it is context free. Build a regex that you think will work for this case and there is probably a case that will break it.

Comment: Sure you can. And I can build you an molto invalid HTML document where libxml throws up big time. I'm pretty sure neither unrealistic edge case is relevant for OP.

Comment: The point is a regexes can fail on a *valid* HTML document while libxml will not.

Comment: Sorry, probably I should have mentioned that I'm intercepting the "certain text" from Wordpress. So unless I'm misuderstanding the suggestion completely, using a parser here isn't the way to go. Text comes from Wordpress as a variable, and I'd like to pass it on as a variable, so Wordpress can finish it off.

Comment: Using DOMDocument is absolutely the right thing to do, now you just need to loop through images and remove the ones that don't match, then call `$var = $doc->saveHTML()` at the end and pass on the filtered HTML.

Comment: Since I already have this working fine with preg_replace_callback - is there a huge difference between that message and DOMDocument performance-wise, or is this mostly a matter of taste and style?

Comment: I would expect DOMDocument to be slower in this particular case but I could be wrong.